# Can I not view 'ts' objects in R

Tags: r, time-series

I recently stumbled upon a rather strange occurrence. While working with time-series data in R, I attempted to View my data like this:

```r
View(AirPassengers)
```

However, it appears that I am unable to do that! No matter the time series, using the command `View()` does not appear to work, and instead of getting to look at the 'ts' object, I get an error informing me:

```r
Error in View: unused argument (optional = TRUE)
```

Of course, I am still quite easily able to work with the data, so this really isn't that big of a deal. But I am curious as to why this may be the case!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error: `View(ts(1:12, frequency = 12))`works perfectly in R version 3.4.3, Rstudio Version 1.1.423

Answer (score 1):

I don't get an error but it is true that the times are not shown.  Suggest you first start a fresh session and then try it.  Also try converting it to zoo and then view it:

```
library(zoo)
View(as.zoo(AirPassengers))
```

Comment: Oddly enough, neither of those work for me. A co-worker of mine can get either of those to work without a problem. I must just have an issue in my version or options settings.

Comment: Does it work if you run a fresh session of R with the --vanilla flag?